# Hibernate + Ehcache updating doesn't straight refresh a cache

Tags: hibernate, caching, ehcache

I use Hibernate annotations on my entities with NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE strategy. How to put an object straight into a cache after updating or saving? In my case, Hibernate loads data from database after update or save operations. Pseudocode:

```
loadUser(); //from DB
loadUser(); //from cache
updateUser(); //updating
loadUser(); //from DB instead of cache
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate does not try to maintain the cache content up to date with modifications. It always evicts entries so that a subsequent query will have to go to the DB and populate the cache with a fresh entry. So what you are asking for is not possible.

This is by design as Hibernate cannot guarantee that all mutations it sees in memory are the complete set of mutations your update causes. Think of having (weird I know) a DB trigger that would cause updates to another column based on updates to a specific one.